# pythonic way to iterate over part of a list

Tags: python, list, iteration

I want to iterate over everything in a list except the first few elements, e.g.:

```
for line in lines[2:]:
    foo(line)
```

This is concise, but copies the whole list, which is unnecessary. I could do:

```
del lines[0:2]
for line in lines:
    foo(line)
```

But this modifies the list, which isn't always good.

I can do this:

```
for i in xrange(2, len(lines)):
    line = lines[i]
    foo(line)
```

But, that's just gross.

Better might be this:

```
for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    if i < 2: continue
    foo(line)
```

But it isn't quite as obvious as the very first example.

So: What's a way to do it that is as obvious as the first example, but doesn't copy the list unnecessarily?

Comment: I think `for i in xrange(2, len(lines)):` is fine.

Comment: just out of curiosity, how large is the list you're iterating over?

Comment: @GregGuida: like 300 lines of text or so

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but for only 300 lines of text, I wouldn't be worrying at all about copying. Remember that only references are being copied, not the string data itself...

Comment: Personally I like the 4th example you put the best. It's no less efficient than the `islice` approach and in my opinion will be easier to read and understand by anyone else looking at your code.

Comment: @thesamet: ah right forgot that the data itself wouldn't be copied. probably true. though i was asking more about the general case

Comment: I too think `for i in xrange(2, len(lines))` is fine, and better than any of the choices below.  Why do you think it's "gross?"

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: cause the pythonic way to iterate is using a `for-each` loop: `for x in stuff:`. you don't do `for i in xrange(len(stuff)): x=stuff[i]`.. so why should you if you just want to do the same iteration but slightly differently?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can try [`itertools.islice(iterable[, start], stop[, step])`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import itertools
for line in itertools.islice(lines, start, stop):
     foo(line)
```

Comment: @NullUserException cheers! was going to add that but my comp had a hiccup

Comment: What would be awesome is something like: `for line in lazy(list)[:2]: foo(line)`, where `lazy` wraps the iterable and if you slice it, calls `islice` instead, etc. That way it looks just like a slice (as it should).

Comment: @Claudiu as slices are supposed to be objects of the same type as the sliced one that would mean that lazy() creates an iterator. It was [discussed on python mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-January/051257.html) and Guido opposed the idea. That doesn't stop independent implementations, but you won't see it in the standard lib very soon.

Comment: WARNING: Can be *extremely* inefficient compared to `list1[start:stop]`. For example, `islice(list1, 100000, 100100)` will *first* iterate over the first 99,999 values (just wont return them). Try it yourself with cProfile; its also in the docs.

Comment: @Jeff Upvoted for being true in cases where calling next `start - 1` times overweights list-slice memory allocation. OP specifically mentioned list slicing as an undesired solution in his question.

Answer (score 28):

The original solution is, in most cases, the appropriate one.

```
for line in lines[2:]:
    foo(line)
```

While this does copy the list, it is only a shallow copy, and is quite quick.  Don't worry about optimizing until you have profiled the code and found this to be a bottleneck.

Comment: ... but if you know that you're going to working with lists with thousands or millions of elements, don't sneer at gifts like `itertools.islice`. In such cases it's worth checking out.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: the phrase "in most cases" is not sneering.

Comment: Even if it's not optimized for large lists, this code has the virtue of readability for small lists.

Answer (score 12):

Although `itertools.islice` appears to be the optimal solution for this problem, somehow, the extra import just seems like overkill for something so simple.

Personally, I find the `enumerate` solution perfectly readable and succinct - although I would prefer to write it like this:

```
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if index >= 2:
        foo(line)
```

Comment: ah personally i prefer to have as few indents as possible. error-checking + continue/return/break/etc first, then the rest is fall-through

Comment: @Claudiu: And what you're saying also gets the intent across immediately; you don't need to look to the end of the `if` block to see if anything is happening after it or in an `else` block.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan. More is less. In the example, a separate `continue` would create a redundant branch in the code, needlessly forcing the reader to parse _two_ blocks of code, rather than one. If the code inside the loop was more complex, then `continue` statements could certainly be used to improve readability by reducing indents. But that is not what the example is attempting to illustrate.

Comment: @ekhumoro: indeed, it depends on the length of the block. I certainly wouldn't go doing it the `continue` way for less than half a dozen lines.

Answer (score 5):

You might build a helper generator:

```
def rangeit(lst, rng):
  for i in rng:
    yield lst[i]

for e in rangeit(["A","B","C","D","E","F"], range(2,4)):
  print(e)
```

Comment: Nice.  But it's limited to lists and won't work well for arbitrary iterables.

Comment: @S.Lott You are right of course. But it meets the requirement of OP and was the first thing which came into my mind - unfortunately I don't memorize all functions of itertools like others seem to ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
for fooable in (line for i,line in enumerate(lines) if i >= 2):
    foo(fooable)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def skip_heading( iterable, items ):
    the_iter= iter( iterable ):
    for i, e in enumerate(the_iter):
        if i == items: break
    for e in the_iter:
        yield e
```

Now you can `for i in skip_heading( lines, 2 ):` without worrying.

Comment: This is basically a special case of `itertools.islice`.

Comment: @delnan: Agreed.  It's a little bit extensible.  Sometimes the real issue is a head/tail processing where the heading has one kind of processing and the tail has a distinct kind of processing.

Comment: How would this work? I just copied it into a small test project and it doesn't print anything - which is also what I'd expect it to do.

Comment: Am I missing something? It looks like `items` goes unused in this function. I think you have a typo/bug.

Comment: @S.Lott I don't write much code in python and assuming there's a bug in code I don't understand on first glance isn't something I'd like to do ;) Your fix is straight forward enough, so there wasn't some kind of clever trick hidden, but who knows.

Comment: @Voo: What?  "assuming there's a bug".  You didn't "assume".  You proved.  What's wrong with proving there's a bug in code you didn't understand?  You provided absolute proof.  Not an assumption.  Proof.

Comment: @S.Lott I proved that it doesn't work with my python3 install (no python 2 version) for the test I wrote - maybe it'd have worked for something other than a string, etc. But yes could've formulated that stronger :)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use [dropwhile](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) for this. It feels natural after using it in Haskell and some other languages, and seems reasonably clear. You can also use it in many other cases where you want to look for a "trigger" condition more complex than the item's index for the start of the iteration.

```
from itertools import dropwhile

for item in dropwhile(lambda x: x[0] < 2, enumerate(lst)):
  # ... do something with item
```

Answer (score 1):

why not just try

```
for i in range(2, len(lines)):
   foo(lines[i])
```

This gives you the index just fine(without doing any copying) and, while you don't get to give the element a proper name(like in enumerate), it strikes me as simple and pythonic. xrange, aside from being deprecated, is less efficient than range since it has to construct the integer each iteration.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: You know, the edit really does add a lot, thanks. I also think this is the best answer and should be accepted. It's efficient and straightforward. Will the world really end if you have to put "line = lines[i]" inside the loop? :D