# Starting from a specific point in a For loop

Tags: python

Is it possible to tell a For loop to start from a specific location?

```
>>> languages = ["C", "C++", "Perl", "Python"] 
>>> for x in languages:
...     print(x)
... 
C
C++
Perl
Python
>>>
```

How can I get the script to begin from "Perl"? I don't need it to loop back around.

Comment: By slicing the list and iterating through that

Comment: [see also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pythonic way to iterate over part of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671280/pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-part-of-a-list)

Answer (score 7):

Lists can be sliced by their indices using `myList[start:stop:skip]`. Starting from the third index (zero-indexing), no stopping, and no skipping of indices, would be:

```
for x in languages[2::]:
    print x
```

would give you:

```
Perl
Python
```

See also: [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: whats with for x in languages[languages.index("Perl")::]?

Comment: @AriGold I'm not sure what that is..it produces a syntax error for me

Comment: really, no way, replace languages[2::] with languages[languages.index("Perl"):], give the index of Perl so no int is needed

Answer (score 3):

You could use `itertools.dropwhile` for this:

```
>>> import itertools

>>> languages = ["C", "C++", "Perl", "Python"] 

>>> for language in itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x != 'Perl', languages):
...     print(language)
... 
Perl
Python
>>>
```

`itertools.dropwhile` takes two arguments, a function that determines whether a list element is equal to your desired starting value, and the iterable - a list in your case - that you want to loop over.  `dropwhile` will skip elements until it finds one that satisfies the function, then it will output all elements until the iterable is exhausted.

This is useful if your criteria for selecting a start point are more complex than simple equality. For example, if you wanted to start from the first element that starts with "P" you can do:

```
>>> for language in itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: not x.startswith('P'), languages):
...     print(language)
... 
Perl
Python
>>>
```

The reverse of this is `itertools.takewhile`, which will iterate for as long as the provided function is satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

```
languages = ["C", "C++", "Perl", "Python"]
# add start index range by the index of "Perl" 
for x in languages[languages.index("Perl"):]:
  print(x)

# Perl
# Python

for x in languages[languages.index("C++"):]:
  print(x)

# C+=
# Perl
# Python
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I hope this will help u

```
languages = ["C", "C++", "Perl", "Python"]

for k in range(0,len(languages)):
  print(languages[k-2])
```

and the output is :

```
Perl
Python
C
C++
```

In python the for loop function is (for k in x(start,stop,step)). Here x is your list or string variable and

```
start : Indicates where the for loop should start and the index starts from zero.

stop : Indicates where the for loop ends. It takes up to (n-1) elements.
```

For example :

```
for k in range(0,100):
```

it gives output till 99 from zero and if u want output of 100. U should mention like this :

```
n = 100
for k in range(n+1):
    print k
```

the output is from 0 to 100. In this case for loop will take indexes (starts) from zero.

```
step : Indicates how many steps should do in for loop. By default step is one in for loop.
```

for example:

```
for k in range(0,10,1):
    print k
#output is 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9


for k in range(0,10,2):
    print k
#output is 0,2,4,6,8

for k in range(0,10,3):
    print k
#output is 0,3,6,9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
languages = ["C", "C++", "Perl", "Python"]
for i in range(languages.index("Perl"),len(languages)):
    # 1st parameter of range will find Perl's index from list languages
    #2nd parameter - Length of list
    print languages[i]


Perl
Python
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want elements from start of perl to the end of list

```
languages = ["C", "C++", "Perl", "Python"]
print languages
```

Its very easy by list slicing

```
print languages[2:]
```

output :

```
['Perl', 'Python']
```

you can loop this list and get elements on separate line.

And Even if you want to get the loopback elements from perl to back-to-perl then also you can use list slicing

```
a = []
a.extend(languages[2:])
a.extend(languages[:2])
print a
```

output:

```
['Perl', 'Python', 'C', 'C++']
```